# Unexpected string in JSON at position 471

Tags: json, angular, angular-cli

I changed the UTF-8 but it doesn't work.

```
C:\Users\arij\premierprojet>ng serve
Parsing angular-cli.json failed. Please make sure your angular-cli.json 
is  valid JSON. Error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 471
```

How to fix this Error ?

Comment: Update your question with angular-cli.json file

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your angular-cli is not valid json file.
You can use a tool like [Json Validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to find where the issue is
and fix it.